# How to overcome Socket Exception in android emulator in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I often get the below mentioned error while running test cases through maven in eclipse (Using Robotium).

```
05-24 19:03:39.112 D/dalvikvm(  441): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2038K, 50% free 8431K/16775K, external 18832K/20738K, paused 9ms+8ms
05-24 19:03:40.032 I/System.out(  441): successtrue
05-24 19:03:40.212 D/dalvikvm(  441): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2091K, 51% free 8387K/16775K, external 18832K/20738K, paused 7ms+8ms
05-24 19:06:07.962 D/SntpClient(   77): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
05-24 19:11:07.972 D/SntpClient(   77): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
05-24 19:16:07.982 D/SntpClient(   77): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

**I checked through different blogs where people mentioned different kind of reasons. Anyone is having any valid reason for the error?**

Code is designed in a fashion to create & close connections. Moreover I faced this issue even when I dont perform a network operation.

Comment: Could you add the code snippet that fails?

Comment: I use maven plugin for eclipse. even the same error i'm getting in Mac also. So hopefully it doesn't relate to OS by any means. Now I'm getting the same eoor in eclipse helios & indigo & in all types of emulator including the intel harware accelerated android emulator also.

Comment: Its not about any particular case. While testing my project through Robotium we are getting this exception which is blocking the next test cases to execute further.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for this exception. Because once this occurs in test case the emulator becomes kind of freeze. Is there any proper documentation available anywhere from eclipse team?